# Unit Tests and incapsulation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

For example, I have a class, working with `HttpClient`

```
public class DomainActions : IDomainActions
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DomainActions(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _client = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration.GetSection("DomainRegistration:BaseAddress").Value)
        };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _configuration.GetSection("DomainRegistration:Token").Value);
    }

    public async Task<List<DomainDto>> GetDomainListAsync()
    {
        var responseMessage = await _client.GetAsync("domains");
        return await ProcessingDomainListResponseAsync(responseMessage);
    }
```

then we resolve it by the following way:

```
    services.AddTransient<IConfiguration>(....);
    services.AddTransient<IDomainActions, DomainActions>();
```

and client class:

```
public class AddMxRecordToRegistrator
{
    protected readonly IDomainActions domainActions;
    public AddMxRecordToRegistrator(IDomainActions domainActions )
    {
        this.domainActions = domainActions ;
    }

    public async Task CreateDomainRecordAsync()
    {
            await domainActions.CreateDomainRecordAsync(queueItem.DomainForRegistration.DomainName, new DomainRegistrationCore.Models.DomainRecordDto
            {
                Content = queueItem.MxRecord,
                Name = String.Empty,
                Priority = 0,
                Ttl = 3600,
                Type = DomainRecordType.MX.ToString(),
                Regions = null
            });
```

ok, it works fine.

Right now, I want to create unit test for AddMxRecordToRegistrator class , but I don't want to use real httpClient. How to do it? Of course, I can add one more dependency:

```
public class DomainActions : IDomainActions
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DomainActions(IConfiguration configuration, HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _client = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration.GetSection("DomainRegistration:BaseAddress").Value)
        };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _configuration.GetSection("DomainRegistration:Token").Value);
    }


    public DomainActions(IConfiguration configuration) : this(configuration, new HttpClientHandler())
    {
    }

    public async Task<List<DomainDto>> GetDomainListAsync()
    {
        var responseMessage = await _client.GetAsync("domains");
        return await ProcessingDomainListResponseAsync(responseMessage);
    }
```

then modify DI composition root:

```
    services.AddTransient<IConfiguration>(....);
    services.AddTransient<HttpMessageHandler>(....);
    services.AddTransient<IDomainActions, DomainActions>();
```

but then why client part (in our case composition root) should know anything about internal detail of `DomainActions` only because we need to create unit test? It like we violate incapsulation for unit tests. How to implement it correctly?

Comment: Your problem is exactly here: `domainActions = new DomainActions(configuration);`. That's completely wrong, clients should never new up dependencies

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, why not? Client pass configuration settings and it's normal

Comment: Because that goes against the Dependency Inversion principle? That's not normal, it's wrong. Either use DI or don't

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, unfortunately, Azure Functions do not work stable and correctly with DI.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto edited my question with DI principle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on the comment from @CamiloTerevinto, `AddMxRecordToRegistrator` should depend on `IDomainActions` via dependency injection, i.e. that interface should be the argument passed to its constructor.

From an encapsulation perspective, `AddMxRecordToRegistrator` shouldn't know that `DomainActions` depends on `IConfiguration` or `HttpMessageHandler`. It shouldn't even know that `DomainActions` exists, because that's a concrete class, and `AddMxRecordToRegistrator` should depend on interfaces, not concrete classes.

Comment: I can't use DI in such case. In any case, in dependency injection composition root we have to configure `IConfiguration` and `HttpMessageHandler`...

Comment: Dependencies on concrete classes create difficulty for unit testing. [Programming to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1371329) helps to alleviate that difficulty and facilitate simpler unit tests.

Comment: I know about DI. Probably, not good example. But in composition root we will have the same problem

Comment: When `AddMxRecordToRegistrator` depends only on `IDomainActions` the former can be unit tested simply by mocking the latter.

Answer (score 0):

> but then why client part (in our case composition root) should know
>   anything about internal detail of DomainActions only because we need
>   to create unit test?

Composition root is only place in application which will "know" about all lower level dependencies.
"Composition" root's role is to compose required classes with runtime implementations.

Class `AddMxRecordToRegistrator` clearly depends on abstraction `IDomainActions`, so for unit testing `AddMxRecordToRegistrator` you just pass fake implementation of `IDomainActions`.